# Tipagem personalizada

Tags: php, tipagem, sintaxe, conversão-de-tipo

> Segundo a [DOC Manipulação de tipos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.type-juggling.php), as conversões permitidas são:
>
> ```
> (int), (integer)          - molde para inteiro
> (bool), (boolean)         - converte para booleano
> (float), (double), (real) - converte para número de ponto flutuante
> (string)                  - converte para string
> (array)                   - converte para array
> (object)                  - converte para objeto
> (unset)                   - converte para NULL (PHP 5)
> ```

---

Queria saber se existe alguma forma de criar uma tipagem personalizada. Procurei em na documentação e no SO-EN mas não achei nada referente a isso.

Já tenho uma função para esse fim, mas queria criar uma tipagem tipo `(upper) 'Papa Chalie' // PAPA CHARLIE`, seria possível?

Comment: Creio que não possível, http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php . "Possibles values of type are: ..." . Aí pode ver os tipos possíveis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP não tem *cast* de verdade. Ele possui funções que fazem conversão de valores. Lembre-se que PHP é dinamicamente tipada, então o tipo da variável não importa e o *cast* serve para compatibilizar um valor com uma variável.

Para converter valores serve qualquer função. Você não terá a sintaxe de *cast*, mas é algo até bom para deixar claro que aquilo é uma conversão. Então crie uma função que interprete os valores do objeto recebido e crie um novo objeto dentro da possibilidade dele. Essa função pode ser solta ou pode estar dentro de uma classe, pode ser estática ou de instância.

Na verdade o exemplo dado se pudesse ser usado seria um completo abuso da sintaxe já que sequer muda o tipo.

Veja [como funciona no C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para ter uma ideia como esse operador no fundo é uma função que permite uma sintaxe apropriada **quando é uma coerção de tipo**. PHP não tem isso.

Comment: Sim, o exemplo não muda o tipo, continua como string, mas levando em conta que `'a' === 'A'` é falso, julguei a existência de uma tipagem *upper* e *lower*.

Comment: Não faz sentido. 'a' === 'A' é como comparar 1 === 2; em ambos os casos, você está comparando tipos iguais com valores diferentes.

Answer (score 4):

Não é possível.

Observe ainda que o *cast* ou conversão de dados é usado para transformar um tipo de dado em outro. O que você esta tentando fazer é transformar o 'formato' ou valor de uma variável (string) para caixa alta, e o caminho é utilizar uma função.

Não é preciso implementar uma função para fazer isso, existe as funções nativas do php [strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtoupper.php), [mb_strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-strtoupper.php).

Em resposta porque `'a' === 'A'` é falso: Vou tentar responder de maneira bem informal, não técnica. É porque são valores diferentes, note que o operador === checa por tipo e valor, e `'a'` é diferente de `'A'` tanto quanto de `'b'`. Internamente, cada letra tem um valor número, note o valor de 'a' tem que ser diferente de 'b', 'c', e também de 'A', para que possamos por exemplo imprimir, comparar, etc, um ao invés do outro.